# Can Mirio solidify his body beyond human level hardness?

Tags: my-hero-academia

So there is no explanation for Mirio's strenght making him able to knock hard rock characters like Kirishima. One wikia states he has enhanced strenght. Since he is able to de-solidify his body, and later solidify it to at least human level solid, can it be that he can solidify beyond human level and that makes him able to become harder and stronger to the point of knocking heroes with superhuman resistance? Similar to what another hero from another universe like Vision from Marvel who is also able to desolidify and solidify does? 
Is there any hint/statement in the manga or any guidebook about how much he can solidify his body after de-solidifying?

Comment: There are two easy explanations we know to be true off the top of my head for how he can easily punch Kirishima.  1: he is very strong from training.  2: he can phase a little into  a person with his punch causing a strong repulsion as he phases back in.  The superpower "phasing" implies that the person using the power moves into another dimension (not exactly but close enough) to pass through stuff rather than changing their density.  His power looks like that and that would not fit well with Vision's increasing density further.

Comment: http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/Intangibility